# How to dynamically set the string based on `if` conditions?

Tags: python

I am trying to load an image dynamically based on two different conditions.

Here's the function:

```
def graph_loss (city, model): 

    if city == 1:
    
        if model == 4:
            Loss = ('assets/images/AU_wind_Loss_MLP.png')
    
        if model == 5:
            Loss = ('assets/images/AU_wind_Loss_LSTM.png')
    
        if model == 6:
            Loss = ('assets/images/AU_wind_Loss_CNN.png')
    
    if city == 2:

        if model == 4:
            Loss = ('assets/images/FR_wind_Loss_MLP.png')
    
        if model == 5:
            Loss = ('assets/images/FR_wind_Loss_LSTM.png')

        if model == 6:
            Loss = ('assets/images/FR_wind_Loss_CNN.png')

    if city == 3:

        if model == 4:
            Loss = ('assets/images/DK_wind_Loss_MLP.png')
    
        if model == 5:
            Loss = ('assets/images/DK_wind_Loss_LSTM.png')

        if model == 6:
            Loss = ('assets/images/DK_wind_Loss_CNN.png')

    return (Loss)
```

I would like to reduce this as much as possible but I'm struggling to dynamically change the file name.

Comment: Note that you don't need to wrap your strings and the return value in parenthesis `()`.

Answer (score 5):

Use a dict for each of your two translations: city code and model code.
Then simply build your string from the pieces.

```
city_code = {1:"AU", 2:"FR", 3:"DK"}
model_code = {4:"MLP", 5:"LSTM", 6:"CNN"}

return "assets/images/" + city_code[city] + "_wind_Loss_" + model_code[model] + ".png"
```

Note that any sort of formatting (such as f-string) will make the file name more readable and Pythonic, but I wanted to keep this at your current level of programming.